# SpringMVC - Controller for all files with same file extension

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a SpringMVC application, and I need to create a controller capable of handling all the request for files with a given extension.

So far I have this:

**web.xml**

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>redirectFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**spring-mvc.xml**

```
<bean id="anotherViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" >
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jhtml"/>
  </bean>
```

**Dispatcher Servlet**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/abc/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

How should I write the controller?

Comment: What is your `DispatcherServlet` mapped to?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question with that information.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `@Controller` method like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "**/*.jhtml")
public String handleExtensionRequest() {
    return "viewName";
}
```

This will map to paths like

```
www.yourhost.com/abc/somePath.jhtml
www.yourhost.com/abc/asdasdasd/qweqwe1231/12312312/somePath.jhtml
```

going down any number of sub paths.

The problem with this is `/abc/somePath` and `/abc/somePath.*` are considered equivalent. If you have a `@Controller` handler method mapped to `/somePath`, it will probably get priority.

With Java config, you can declare a `@Configuration` class to extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and add

```
@Override
@Bean
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
    RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    return handlerMapping;
}
```

This setting decides

> Whether to use suffix pattern match (".*") when matching patterns to
>   requests.

The [`RequestMappingHandlerMapping`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html) has other methods/settings you can play around with to set the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I opted for the easiest way: since what I only need is to redirect those *.jhtml requests to somewhere else, I added a filter for them.

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <description>Filter for *.jhtml requests</description>
    <display-name>jhtmlRedirectFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>jhtmlRedirectFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.mycompany.JHTMLRedirectFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jhtmlRedirectFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**JHTMLRedirectFilter class**

```
public class JHTMLRedirectFilter implements Filter {


    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JHTMLRedirectFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {       

        // Some logic here
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```